# jQuery if condition with parent style attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have such variant's off html p-container:

sometime so:

```
<p style="text-align:center"><div class="caption left" style="width: 600px;"><img alt="Черный винил на капоте Фокуса - рельефный, его узор объемный" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/426/content_ydhrmn4ow-k.jpg" style="height:398px; width:600px" class="cboxElement"><p>dsf</p></div></p>
```

but somethime's it's so:

```
<p><div class="caption left" style="width: 600px;"><img alt="Винил для некоторых владельцев авто - больше чем просто тюнинг" src="/ckeditor_assets/pictures/427/content_fbl-djoq5ka.jpg" style="height:441px; width:600px" class="cboxElement"><p>Винил для некоторых владельцев авто - больше чем просто тюнинг</p></div></p>
```

and all my javascript code is for first div in P-tag.

Could i check for div (class="caption left") it's parent: did it include style="text-align:center" or not? Could it be written in jQuery or not? And how?

Comment: `if($('.caption.left').parent().css('text-align') === 'center')`

Comment: Very important thing: you CAN'T have `<p><p></p></p>`. It will break your DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to access parent css attribute. I'll do it this way :

```
var styPar = $( ".caption.left" ).parent().css( "text-align" );
```

then cheking :

```
if (styPar == "center")
{
   //Do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```
if( $('.caption.left').parent().css( 'text-align' ) === 'left' ) {
    // do some things
}
```

if you have few `div` elements with class `caption left` better to use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method:

```
$( '.caption.left' ).each( function() {
    if( $( this ).parent().css( 'text-align' ) === 'left' ) {
        // some stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Main question is what you exactly need that for. Using jQuery:

```
if($('div.caption.left').parent().css('text-align') == 'center')
```

**Very important thing: you CAN'T have `<p><p></p></p>`. It will break your DOM.**